# ramification index in an example

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $L=\mathbb{Q}_5[x]/(x^4+5x^2+5)$, where $\mathbb{Q}_5$ is the field of 5-adic numbers. Note that the polynomial that we are quotienting out by is an Eisenstein polynomial. So $L/\mathbb{Q}_5$ is a totally ramified extension, and hence its ramification index should equal the degree, which is $4$. I'm trying to see why, directly from the definition of ramification index $e$, i.e $5O_L=m_L^e$, why is $e=4$? I see that from $5=-x^4-5x^2$ that $5 \in (x)^2$. I'm guessing $m_L=(x)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $v_5$ be the normalized valuation on $\mathbb{Q}_5$, so $v_5(5)=1$. Then the Newton polygon of $f(x)=x^4+5x^2+5$ has slope $\frac{1}{4}$, so if $\alpha$ is a root of $f$ then $v_5(\alpha)=\frac{1}{4}$. This implies that $5\mathcal{O}_L=(\alpha)^4$.

You are correct that $5\in (x)^2$, but $x^2\not\in (5)$, so it's not true that $(5)=(x^2)$. Instead, $(5)=(x^4)$, since
$$ 5=\frac{-x^4}{x^2+1}=\frac{-x^4(x^2+4)}{x^4+5x^2+4}=x^4(x^2+4)$$

Answer (score 0):

Here may be a more concrete way to see it. Since $(5) \in (x)^2$, then the equation $5=-x^4-5x^2$ shows that $5 \in (x^4) + (x^2)(x^2) = (x^4)$ 
If the equation had been $5=-x^4-5x$, then we would first conclude $5 \in (x)$, and then using this we get $5 \in (x^4) + (x)(x)= (x^2)$, and so on, until we get $5 \in (x^4)$.
And more generally, the same argument shows that modding out by an Eisenstein will give a totally ramified extension.